# Donutcache Mvc3 and areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, asp.net-mvc-routing, outputcache

Im having a problem getting donutcaching to work on an area i MVC3.

It seems that the "area"-attribute doesnt get passed along in the routeValueDictionary to the HtmlHelper Action-method in MvcDonutCaching.

I have a childaction that gets called like this: `@Html.Action("Header", "Menu", true)`, and that works fine for all controllers that are not ind an area - but as soon it lies within an area, it cannot de found:

***"The controller for path '/Indberetning/Administration/Index' was not found or does not implement IController."***

I found out that the area doesnt get passed along to the exensionmethod that renders the action. Anyone has a solution for this? :)

AreaRegistration:
  `public class IndberetningAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "Indberetning";
            }
        }`

```
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
          "Indberetning_DiscoHovedgruppe",
          "Indberetning/Disco/Hovedgrupper/{hovedgruppe}",
          new { controller = "Disco", action = "Hovedgrupper", hovedgruppe = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
        context.MapRoute(
                      "Indberetning_FejlrapportIlOptaelling",
                      "Indberetning/Fejlrapport/IlOptaelling/il{iltype}/{fejltype}/side-{page}",
                      new { controller = "Fejlrapport", action = "IlOptaelling", page = 1 }
                  );


        context.MapRoute(
          "Indberetning_FejlrapportIpOptaelling",
          "Indberetning/Fejlrapport/IpOptaelling/ip{iptype}/{fejltype}/side-{page}",
          new { controller = "Fejlrapport", action = "IpOptaelling", page = 1 }
      );

        context.MapRoute(
         "Indberetning_Fejlrapport",
         "Indberetning/Fejlrapport/{action}/",
         new { controller = "Fejlrapport", action = "Fejlrapport" }
     );

        context.MapRoute(
          "Indberetning_VirksomhedUgyldigArbejdssted",
          "Indberetning/Virksomhed/UgyldigArbejdssted/{pnummer}/side-{page}/{tmetode}",
          new { controller = "Virksomhed", action = "UgyldigArbejdssted", page = 1, tmetode = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );

        context.MapRoute(
         "Indberetning_VirksomhedArbejdssted",
         "Indberetning/Virksomhed/Arbejdssted/{denr}/side-{page}/{tmetode}",
         new { controller = "Virksomhed", action = "Arbejdssted", page = 1, tmetode = UrlParameter.Optional }
     );

        context.MapRoute(
        "Indberetning_VirksomhedArbejdssteder",
        "Indberetning/Virksomhed/Arbejdssteder/side-{page}",
        new { controller = "Virksomhed", action = "Arbejdssteder", page = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

        context.MapRoute(
           "Indberetning_DiscoDetaljer",
           "Indberetning/Disco/Detaljer/Hoveddiscogruppe-{id}/{jobStatus}",
           new { controller = "Disco", action = "Detaljer", jobStatus = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
        context.MapRoute(
            "Indberetning_default",
            "Indberetning/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Forside", action = "Forside", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

The code runs fine without the outputcache implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use this overload of the `Html.Action` method:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Action(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
                                        string actionName,
                                        string controllerName,
                                        object routeValues,
                                        bool excludeFromParentCache)
```

And in you your case:

```
@Html.Action("Header", "Menu", new { Area = "AreaName" }, true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :) Unfornunately, it doesnt work. I can see the area gets passed along just fine now, the funny thing is that when the code executes (after i've had the exception), the routevaluedictionary is emptied. It now has a length of 0 entries. Very strange

Comment: https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=CBE35DBDC1780EE6&id=CBE35DBDC1780EE6%219096&v=3 (an image showing that the area is passed along)

https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=CBE35DBDC1780EE6&id=CBE35DBDC1780EE6%219097&v=3 (an image 1 singlestep further, now the routvaluedictionary is empty)

Comment: Add more code to the question, show the requested Controller.Action code, as well the AreaRegistration.

Comment: What if you call the requested Action directly (not using `@Html.Action`)?

Comment: I have updated the question :)

The controller/action to be invoed is simple:

 public ActionResult Index()
        {
          
            return View(new AdministrationIndexViewModel());
        }

Comment: It has a "ChildAction"-attribute, so i get "The action 'Header' is accessible only by a child request."

Comment: Oh my god! could it be that the "area"-attribute  from the dynamic type entered as the routvaluedictionary in the Html.Action method is case-sensitive?. Changed the _new { Area = "AreaName" }_ to _new { area = "AreaName" }_    ..... That did the trick

Comment: Strange indeed. i doubt it was the reason for the problem.